# I am getting error 403 when I test controller endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, mockito, junit4

I know that I should change something in websecurityConfig, but what exactly I can't find.Here is my websecurity config.

```
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)
        return http.build()
    }
```

And here I just try to check can I access to the endpoint

```
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = ["ADMIN"])
    fun `testA`()  {
        mvc
            .perform(
                post("/bla/bla")
                    //.with(csrf())
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            ).andExpect(status().isCreated)
    }
```

I tried to use .with(csrf()), but it gives me error 404.

Comment: Is it 403 OR 404?

Comment: Without this line of code  `.with(csrf())` 403, but with it 404.

Comment: Then check the final url, '.with(csrf())' is fine but 404 is happening because of wrong api. Check the final path of api.

Comment: I checked the path and I am sure that it is right. There is something else but what exactly I cant find

Comment: have you checked with postman? Is it working or Not?

Answer (score 0):

So based on your websecurityConfig file, you require that every endpoint will be accessible only by users with role admin.
The error you are getting may be from that, so for testing purpose you can change it to: .anyRequest().permitAll()
Also please check that user has the ADMIN role and if so can you please check also the service of user?

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually I added annotation `(@WithMockUser roles = ["ADMIN"])`, and it should work. Also i tried  permitAll(), but still getting error.